# Can't push to Array inside Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
var tags = new Array();
var tags[4]= new Array();
tags[4].push("Hello");
```

Somehow this doesnt work, console Says on line two that there's an unexpected Token...
Can you help me somehow? Its an Array inside an Array. I simplified the code, because the rest is right.

Thx

Comment: possible duplicate of [push() a two-dimensional array with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345954/push-a-two-dimensional-array-with-javascript)

Comment: @Hast - I really don't see how that is a duplicate...

Comment: @Lix It mentions two-dimensional arrays and pushing, it *must* be a duplicate, don't you *see*? :p

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - gosh I hope you were being sarcastic :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`var tags[4]` is incorrect. Just `tags[4]` is needed.

Comment: @sunfingerde - what error message do you get?  This is all that's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 6):

It's a simple mistake to make.  Just remove `var` from line 2...

```
var tags = new Array();
tags[4]= new Array();
tags[4].push("Hello");
```

`tags[4]` is already available by declaring `tags` on line 1.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `var` before `tags[4]`. `tags` is the variable, `tags[4]` is a property of the object referenced by that variable, not another variable.

```
var tags = new Array();
tags[4]= new Array();
tags[4].push("Hello");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var tags[4] // is incorrect.
// use this
tags[4]= new Array();
tags[4].push("Hello");
```

[var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword creates a variable so old value is lost .

Answer (score 2):

The array `tags` has already been initialized, so you don't need `var` on the second line. Remove it and the code works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `var` before `tag[4]`

Try this instead.

```
var tags = new Array();
tags[4]= new Array();
tags[4].push("Hello");
```