# array of arrays jquery, json to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, push

The JSON  I have:

```
[{"one":"a","two":"1","three":"2","four":"3"},
 {"one":"b","two":"4","three":"5","four":"6"},
 {"one":"c","two":"7","three":"8","four":"9"}]
```

The array that I need:

```
[[[1,"a"], [4,"b"], [7,"c"]],
 [[2,"a"], [5,"b"], [8,"c"]],
 [[3,"a"], [6,"b"], [9,"c"]]]
```

How can I treat the JSON to transform it in an array of arrays?

I need **to do it dynamically** because the JSON could be bigger (more rows a, b, c, ...z). The 4 columns are fixed(one,two,three,four) and won't change.

I have tried several ways...to do it with .push, creating an array=[[]], trying array=new array(3) and then in each position making array[0]=new array[], but i didn't solved yet, I have passed all day trying this, all day!

I think the solution is using push like here [related subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345954/push-a-two-dimensional-array-with-javascript)
But I don't understand this solution very well.

I would appreciate your help please.

Comment: you've got nested arrays, so basically you'll need nested loops.

Comment: Or you can try the `map` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the rows and columns, like below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Castrolol/0x8u352r/1/

```
var sampleData = [{"one":"a","two":"1","three":"2","four":"3"},
 {"one":"b","two":"4","three":"5","four":"6"},
 {"one":"c","two":"7","three":"8","four":"9"}];


function transform(data){

    var prepared = data.map(function(row){
        var keys = Object.keys(row);
        var values = keys.map(function(key){
            return row[key];
        });
        var columnOne = values[0];
        var otherColumns = values.slice(1);

        return {
            letter: columnOne,
            numbers: otherColumns
        };

    });    

    var rows = [];

    prepared.forEach(function(row){

        row.numbers.forEach(function(number, i){

            if( i >= rows.length ){
                rows.push([]);
            }

            rows[i].push([+number, row.letter]);

        });

    });    

    return rows;

}


var result =  transform(sampleData) ;
console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4));
```

Comment: Amazing!! Sincerely I have passed all day with this problem. Now it works PERFECT!! I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In your json its array inside array so the first array is of single item and the second array is for 3 item. So you need to write the inner for loop for getting the second array 2 items like below.

```
for(var i=0; i<info.length; i++)
{
    for(var j=0; j<info[i].length; j++)
    {
        Ti.API.info("Title : " + sample[i][j].one);
        Ti.API.info("Desc : " + sample[i][j].a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i don't have the problem moving inside the array (i can do it with $.each(resultado, function( key, value )   The problem that I have is --> how to build the new array