# How to add data to a 2-D map in Javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, hashmap

I mostly develop in Java, but I presently need to do some work using JavaScript.

I have data that I need to group by two dimensions: first by gender, and then by language. The object to be grouped comes like so:

```
var items =[ {
  "language":"english",
  "gender":"male",
  ...//twelve other fields
},
...
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
var myMap = {};
for(var i=0; i<items.length;i++){
  var item = items[i];
  var _gender = item["gender"];
  var _lang = item["language"];
  myMap[_gender][_lang].push[item];
}
```

I assumed the above would work, but it’s not working. It keeps returning this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'undefined' of undefined
```

Note: In Java, I would be creating a map of arrays.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. `items` is actually an array. It comes as a response from a REST api as an array.

Comment: what you want. give me a example.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing totally wrong. First of all myMap is object not an array so you can not use `myMap.push()`. 
You can achieve like this.

```
var items = {
  "language":"english",
  "gender":"male"
}
var myMap = {};
for(var key in items){
   var myArray = [];
   var _gender = items["gender"];
   var _lang = items["language"];
   myArray.push(_gender);
   myArray.push(_lang);
   myMap.item = myArray;
   console.log(myMap);
}
```

for add  2-d array read this. [2-D Array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345954/push-a-two-dimensional-array-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am going to test. But by just looking, yours looks like an array of maps whereas what I need is a map of arrays. I.e. a map where each key has for value an array of items.

Answer (score 0):

#### One problem:

When you call `myMap[_gender][_lang].push[item];`, what you are actually doing is adding a key to the Object `myMap`, with the current value of `_gender`, and turning it into an Object, which you then create a new key for, set to the value of `_lang`. In addition, `.push()` is a function used with *arrays*, to add a new item onto the end of the array. If you want to add a new key and value to an Object, all you have to do is just call that key and assign it a value. Here's an example.

```js
var obj = {
  ex1 : 'example 1',
  ex2 : 'example 2'
};

console.log(obj);

obj.ex3 = 'example 3';

console.log(obj);

//The code below will simply log 'undefined' in most consoles(it doesn't happen to do so in this snippet).
console.log(obj.ex4);
```

#### Here's my suggestion(assuming I correctly understand what you're trying to do):

```js
var items = [{
  "language":"english",
  "gender":"male",
},
//...more below
];

myMap = [];


for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
  myArray = [];
  var item = items[i];
  var _gender = item["gender"];
  var _lang = item["language"];
  myArray.push(_gender);
  myArray.push(_lang);
  myMap.push(myArray);
}
```